# how to convert a picture to mat with opencv & eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv, image

I have a picture that I had located in the drwable directroy.
I need to use it as a mat file.

I found in the site that I should do this

```
bitmap batt= bitmapFactory.decodeFile("path");
```

`Utils.bitmapToMat(batt,mBatt);`

but it does not seem to work,

am I doing somthing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted should work. What you are probably missing is to initialize the mBatt object.

First, declaring the **batt** object should be **Bitmap** with capital B (maybe this was just a type in your question code):

```
Bitmap batt = bitmapFactory.decodeFile("path");
```

**Then you should do something like this, to initialize mBatt object, before bitmapToMat:**

```
// battHeight and battWidth should have the height and width of your bitmap...
Mat mBatt = new Mat(battHeight, battWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I googled "opencv bitmap to mat", the first three links all address your problem and provide possible solutions...

Seems like the problem is an unstable `bitmapToMat()`-function.

For the solution(s), take a look the pages Google gave me:

1. [Java openCV - Error while conevrting Bitmap to Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684869/java-opencv-error-while-conevrting-bitmap-to-mat)
2. [Correct way to convert between Bitmap and Mat in OpenCV on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637316/correct-way-to-convert-between-bitmap-and-mat-in-opencv-on-android)
3. [A Simple Question - How do I convert between Bitmap and Mat?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-opencv/8EoxpTb4W3E)

The first two here are actually on stackoverflow, didn't they show as similar questions when you typed your question?

Good luck!