# After converting image to bitmap, image doesn't displayed

Tags: java, android, opencv, bitmap, mat

When I'm trying to convert the Mat image to Bitmap the image doesn't displayed in my device, on the contrary when I use `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` the displayed image is black.
Here is my code:

```
Mat src = new Mat(bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        imgToProcess = Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, src);

        Bitmap bmpOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgToProcess.cols(), imgToProcess.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(imgToProcess, bmpOut);
        imv.setImageBitmap(bmpOut);
        rotateImage(bmpOut);
```

Answer (score 0):

matToBitmap is known to be buggy. As a workaround, try to convert your image to different colorspace before converting to bitmap:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(imgToProcess, result, Imgproc. COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(result.cols(), result.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(result, bmp);
```

See related issue [Correct way to convert between Bitmap and Mat in OpenCV on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637316/correct-way-to-convert-between-bitmap-and-mat-in-opencv-on-android)

Comment: I tried to convert it to different colorspace, but the app is stopped working.